Why do we multiply representations of fields with the imaginary unit if they represent timelike directions?
I am reading section 3 of Antoine van Proeyen notes on tools for supersummetry. Ultimately, I want to understand the Clifford algebra in d=t+s spacetime dimensions to improve my understanding of it as an operator basis (section 2.2.1) and in the context of SYK.
My question is: why is the following statement true? (Antione on page 17)

if there are $t$ timelike directions, we just have to multiply the first $t$ matrices in the representation above by $i$.

Could it be that this is a consequence of the way the spinors appear in the t+s dimensional Dirac equation?

Its not complicated (compared to the rest of supersymmetry!). If you want
$$
\gamma^a \gamma^b+\gamma^b \gamma^a = 2\eta^{ab}
$$
where $\eta= {\rm diag}(-,-,\ldots, +,+)$ with $t$ minus signs and $d$ plus signs, and you already have (usually hermitian) $\gamma$'s with
$$
\gamma^a \gamma^b+\gamma^b \gamma^a = 2\delta^{ab},
$$
then all you need to get one from the other is to multiply each of the first $t$ hermitan $\gamma$'s by $i$. Then the new matrices still anticommute but the first $t$ now square to $-{\mathbb I}$ rather than $+{\mathbb I}$.
In the context of SYK the $\gamma^a$ are called $\psi^a$ and regarded as Majorana mode operators. There is no Dirac equation as such.

This satisfactory solves my question above. Thank you!
Regarding your remark on SYK: I thought we could write the Lagrangian as $\propto\psi\partial_t\psi-H_\text{SYK}$, that is, I thought the Dirac Lagrangian would contribute towards the kinetic term.
Maybe I should make a new question, but, could you possibly recommend some sources that make it more clear what happens to the Dirac equation in d=t+s dimensional Majorana field theories?

@ jrobins
You can look at my arXiv:2009.00518, although its philisophy might be different from what you ask.
